# How to match against a date in SUMPRODUCT in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum cells from column B whenever cells from column A matches a date. I am able to do this successfully like so:

=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=DATEVALUE("7/9/21"))*B1:B10)

, however I need the date to come from a different cell, which has a format of date. I tried this:

=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=X1)*B1:B10)

, but it return "0".

I tried different variants but none of them seems to work:

=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=X1)*DATEVALUE(B1):B10)

, errors out with #VALUE!

Any advice on what I can try?

Comment: Is X1 a date or text-that-looks-like-a-date?  If changing the cell's format to General makes it display a number, then it's a date. Otherwise it's the latter.

Comment: If X1 is not a real, numeric date then this should also work: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=DATEVALUE(X1))*B1:B10)`. However, to enter a true date would be preferable and in that case the formula you tried is the correct one to use.

Comment: Why not you are using `SUMIFS()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

but this seems to have work for me :

**=SOMMEPROD((A1:A10=N(X1))*B1:B10)***

Basically N() Function turns the cell into a number which allows you to do the comparison.

But like the Variatus in the comments said your original function also worked for me.
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10=X1)*B1:B10)

[Picture spreadsheet]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcW1O.png

Comment: Thank you, I followed all recommendations here and it works. Simplified with SUMIFS and then made sure I am using a date as the cell format.